# Optimizar una consulta con una subconsulta repetida de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, revisión-de-código, rendimiento

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA_A
WHERE 
CAMPO_1 IN (
  SELECT CAMPO_X FROM TABLA_B
)
OR
CAMPO_2 IN (
  SELECT CAMPO_X FROM TABLA_B
)
```

La consulta funciona, espero que se pueda optimizar la llamada de los `in` ya que son iguales. Me queda la duda si hay una penalización de rendimiento, ya que se hacen dos llamadas a la misma consulta

**Edit**
Tanto `TABLA_A` como `TABLA_B` pueden contener registros duplicados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando [`EXISTS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), que comprueba que al menos haya un registro, sólo se genera la subconsulta 1 vez para ambas columnas:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM TABLA_A
 WHERE EXISTS (
         SELECT CAMPO_X
           FROM TABLA_B
          WHERE (TABLA_A.CAMPO_1 = TABLA_B.CAMPO_X)
             OR (TABLA_A.CAMPO_2 = TABLA_B.CAMPO_X)
       )
```

<kbd>[Demo en SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73193/1/0)</kbd>

---

Y, yendo un paso más en la simplificación, podemos usar el `IN` en el sentido opuesto:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM TABLA_A
 WHERE EXISTS (
         SELECT CAMPO_X
           FROM TABLA_B
          WHERE TABLA_B.CAMPO_X
             IN (TABLA_A.CAMPO_1, TABLA_A.CAMPO_2)
       )
```

<kbd>[Demo en SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73193/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: Al final lo hice con la segunda opción

Comment: Claramente es mejor la segunda consulta, pero me pareció más didáctico explicado así.

Comment: Opino igual un usuario futuro lo comprendera mejor asi :)

Answer (score 3):

[INNER JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-Pe/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx) Es la opción más simple

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA_A as a
INNER JOIN TABLA_B  as b 
ON a.CAMPO_1 =b.CAMPO_1  OR a.CAMPO_2 = b.CAMPO_1
```

Hay que decir que el `or` se puede reemplazar con [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-PE/library/ms180026.aspx) para mejorar el rendimiento de su consulta , no especifica en su pregunta pero esta solución puede retornar duplicados si tanto el valor de a.CAMPO_1 y a.CAMPO_2 están en la TABLA_B.

@Mariano Gracias por el aporte

```
SELECT CAMPO_1,CAMPO_2
FROM TABLA_A
WHERE CAMPO_1 IN (
SELECT CAMPO_X
FROM TABLA_B)
UNION 
SELECT CAMPO_1, CAMPO_2
FROM TABLA_A
WHERE CAMPO_2 IN (
SELECT CAMPO_X
FROM TABLA_B);
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f24580/1)

Comment: Buena solución, pero haría que devuelva registros duplicados si tanto el valor de `a.CAMPO_1` **y** `a.CAMPO_2` están en la `TABLA_B`

Comment: Y si se le añade un DISTINCT ?

Comment: Podría ser, pero no sabemos si pueden o no existir valores duplicados originales en `TABLA_A` (en todo caso, lo debería aclarar el autor)

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con Mariano, solo que omitiría el campo en la consulta del EXISTS, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLA_A
 WHERE EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
           FROM TABLA_B
          WHERE TABLA_B.CAMPO_X
             IN (TABLA_A.CAMPO_1, TABLA_A.CAMPO_2)
       )
```

PS: Disculpas por no poder comentar sobre la respuesta de Mariano, pero es que no tengo suficientes puntos todavía.

Comment: Esto es casi un mito urbano. `EXISTS` se encarga de obtener la mínima información posible de la subconsulta, por lo que **ignora** la parte del `SELECT`. No hay ninguna diferencia en si se usa 1, campo, * o X... Esto [está explicado en el 2do párrafo del manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) (*MySQL ignores the `SELECT` list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference*)

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano no sabia eso.

Answer (score -1):

Efectivamente el JOIN es la mejor manera de optimizar la consulta, solo que aquí lo que tenemos que aclarar, es que dependiendo del problema al que le quieras dar solución, puedes utilizar JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, LEFT JOIN.

Como ya lo mencionaron ates, es necesario saber mas acerca de lo que se busca solucionar.

Así que te recomiendo leas un poco de el Join, y sinceramente en el trabajo es muy común que encuentres consultas que utilizan JOIN, así que ve agarrando cariño a esa clausula.

Saludos.